# Undisabled button if at least one checkbox were checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code like below:

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(event) {
      $('.chuis').each(function() {
      if(this.checked) {
          $('#delete_all_vm').prop("disabled",false);   
      }
      else {
          $('#delete_all_vm').prop("disabled",true)   
      }
      });
     })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="chuis" type="checkbox"  />
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox"  />
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox" />
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox"  />
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox"  />
<button id="delete_all_vm" disabled="disabled">Click me!</button>
```

I want the button with `id="delete_all_vm"` un-disabled if the 1 of 5 checkbox are checked (at least one checkbox were checked), so when there is a checkbox at least one were checked, it will undsiabled the button `id="delete_all_vm"`. How can i do that ?

Comment: You can use `if($('.chuis').is(':checked')){`

Comment: Probably you will find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426482/how-to-disable-other-checkbox-on-click-of-one-check-box) and it is possible duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it but you don't need to loop through the elements.

use this as your if condition. `$('.chuis').is(':checked')`

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(event) {
  if ($('.chuis').is(':checked')) {
    $('#delete_all_vm').prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $('#delete_all_vm').prop("disabled", true)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox" />
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox" />
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox" />
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox" />
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox" />
<button id="delete_all_vm" disabled="disabled">Click me!</button>
```

> **Update:** Optional method.

If you want to cut the source code down a little more you can use `!$('.chuis').is(':checked')` to set the `.prop()` value so no if condition will be needed at all.

```js
$('.chuis').click(function(){
  $('#delete_all_vm').prop("disabled", !$('.chuis').is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox"/>
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox"/>
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox"/>
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox"/>
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox"/>
<button id="delete_all_vm" disabled="disabled">Click me!</button>
```

If you have any questions about the source code above please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: @Gagantous You are very welcome. I have updated the answer to include a second method which is slightly smaller and I think looks much more simple to work with/around.

Answer (score 1):

Get all the number of checked checkbox, if not 0, enable.

It is advisable to use the class `.chuis` instead of `input[type=checkbox]` as selector

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".chuis").click(function() {
   
    //Get the number of checked checkbox
    var num = $(".chuis:checked").length;

    //Check if number is not 0, enable the btn
    if (num !== 0) {
      $('#delete_all_vm').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $('#delete_all_vm').prop("disabled", true);
    }

  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox" />
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox" />
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox" />
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox" />
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox" />
<button id="delete_all_vm" disabled="disabled">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `each` function you are iterating over all the input elements and if an item is checked you are either disabling or enabling the disabled prop on the button. This would only work as you would expect if the last input is checked. What if the first 1 input is checked but the last is not? The function would enable the button first then when it gets to the last input it would disable it. So I think all that you need to do is this:

```
 $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(event) {
      $('.chuis').each(function() {
         if(this.checked) {
           $('#delete_all_vm').prop("disabled", false);   
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it without using JQuery.

```js
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("chuis");
var btn = document.getElementById("delete_all_vm");
var len = checkboxes.length;
var checkCounter = 0;

while(len--) {
  var chkbox = checkboxes[len];
  chkbox.onchange = function() {
    checkCounter += this.checked ? 1 : -1;
    btn.disabled = checkCounter === 0 ? true : false;
  };
}
```

```html
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox"  />
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox"  />
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox" />
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox"  />
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox"  />
<button id="delete_all_vm" disabled="disabled">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(event) {
      var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
       var checkedOne = Array.prototype.slice.call(checkboxes).some(x => x.checked);
      
      if(!checkedOne ) {
          $('#delete_all_vm').prop("disabled",true);   
      }
      else {
          $('#delete_all_vm').prop("disabled",false)   
      }
      
     })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="chuis" type="checkbox"  />
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox"  />
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox" />
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox"  />
<input class="chuis" type="checkbox"  />
<button id="delete_all_vm" disabled="disabled">Click me!</button>
```

Try this code and please let me know if this is working fine.